# Nothing being displayed by Pygame

Tags: python, graphics, pygame, drawing, surface

I am using Pygame for the first time so I am following a tutorial online. I recreated the code almost exactly and the window opens normally but nothing will display. I've tried copying other examples for simple Pygame setup and each time I run it the window opens but nothing else happens.

I am using python 3.7.5

Here is my code for reference:

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *

    def game_init() :

        global SURFACE_MAIN

        SURFACE_MAIN = pygame.display.set_mode( ( GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT ) )

        pygame.display.set_caption( "rouge_like" )

    def game_draw() :

        # Clear  surface
        SURFACE_MAIN.fill( COLOR_DEFAULT_BG )

        # Draw map

        # Draw player
        SURFACE_MAIN.blit( PLAYER_SPRITE, ( 100, 100 ) )

        # Update display
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()

    def game_main_loop() :

        while True :

            # Process events
            for event in pygame.event.get() :
                #print(event)
                if event.type == QUIT :
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            # Draw Game
            game_draw()

    def main() :

        pygame.init()

        game_init()
        game_main_loop()

    if __name__ == '__main__' :
        main()
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that pygame is registering the events in `pygame.event.get()` which rules out the window not running or being frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is an issue with VSCode. Running the program from my regular computer terminal works just fine.